# Can i find largest sequence of multiples of given n positive greater than 1 integers?

Tags: integers, coprime

Suppose i have $n$ positive $q_i>1, i\in\{1,2\dots n\}$ integers. The multiples of these $q_i>1$ integers form sequences on number line with length $l\geqslant1$. My question is: Is it possible, for given $q_i>1$ integers to calculate maximum possible value for $l$? I do not want to use "brute-force" type approach. What would be most efficient way doing it?

If it simplifies the problem, one can also assume that $q_i>1$ integers are coprime.

For example: Suppose $n=2, q_1=2, q_2=3 $ the sequences of multiples (I denote valid sequences with curly braces) of $q_1\ and \ q_2\ are \ \{0\},1,\{2,3,4\},5,\{6\},7,\{8,9,10\},11,\{12\}\dots$ 
As you can see from example, the available values for $l$ are finite, because they repeat themselves after $6,12\dots$ The Longest sequence is $\{1,2,3\}, \{8,9,10\}\dots$ and I expect the answer of $l$ to be $3$

Comment: Not following.  What causes the sequence(s) to terminate?  Why aren't there infinitely many members of each sequence?  Perhaps it would help if you gave an explicit example.  Say $q_1=2,q_2=3$.  What's the answer you want in that case and why?

Comment: @lulu i have edited my answer. Under number line i mean number line of positive integers

Comment: I think usage of the word "consecutive" might make this question clearer, if I'm interpreting it correctly.

Comment: How is $\{1,2,3\}$ an example?  If you are looking for consecutive strings of multiples, then $\{2,3,4\}$ would be an example for $q_1=2,q_2=3$.  Indeed, it is clear that you can't have a sequence of length $4$ since no two consecutive odd numbers are both multiples of $3$.

Comment: @lulu I imagine that's a typo - in the list the triple $\{2,3,4\}$ is clearly marked.

Comment: More broadly, for coprime $q_i$, it is clear that you only need to search up to $\prod q_i$ since everything is periodic with that modulus.  Thus, in this particular example, you only need to search up to $6$.

Comment: But what is the source of this problem?  What have you tried?  For $n=2$ it is easy to sort the answer out, for example.  Why not start there?

Comment: A related concept is the Jacobsthal function (which is treated many places on the web).

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A059756 where it is noted, for example, that for the numbers $2,3,5,7,11,13$ you get $\ell=17$ using $2184,2185,\dots,2200$.

Answer (score 1):

If the $q_i$ are coprime the pattern will repeat after the product of all the $q_i$, so if you are doing brute force you can stop there.  In your example with $2,3$ you could stop after $6$ and know you have the longest consecutive sequence.

You can do better, but it is hard to describe as an algorithm.  Let's say we have the $q_i 2,3,5,13$.  This will not repeat until $390$.  We can make a row 
$$2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2\_2$$
which shows that $2$ divides every other number but the alternate ones are not accounted for yet.  Now fill in a blank with $3$ and note that it will repeat every $6$.  There is another multiple of $3$ in the middle, but that number is already a multiple of $2$.  That gives $$232\_2\_232\_2\_232\_2\_232\_2\_232\_2\_232$$
Now we note that the $5$s will come $10$ apart and there are always at least two blanks between them.  Putting a $5$ in the blank right after a $3$ makes the next occurence of $5$ land on a $3$, so we wait one.  We can only fill one of those with a $13$, so it becomes
$$232(13)25232\_2\_23252\_232\_2\_232\_2\_232$$
which shows we can get nine numbers in order with this set.  The Chinese remainder theorem guarantees this pattern exists somewhere because the first number is the solution to $$n\equiv 0 \pmod 2\\n\equiv 2 \pmod 3\\n\equiv 0 \pmod 5\\n \equiv 10 \pmod {13}$$